# Multiple Instances of CasperJS/phantomJS for load testing

Tags: load-testing, phantomjs, casperjs, multiple-users

is there a possibility to perform load testing with casperJS/phantomJS? I haven't found out anything about this. My exact situation is that I should test a Webproject in my company. Is there a possibility to simulate many users accessing this site simultaneously with casperJS/phantomJS?

Thank you and regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, casper and phantom are not really meant for load testing - they are meant for testing your frontend code, making sure that the right thing happens when you press a button, etc.

For load testing I would recommend a dedicated benchmarking tool, such as apache bench (comes with your apache installation, so if you have wamp intalled you already have it). It measures the load time of each page, and gives you various statistics about the requests such as fastest, slowest, normal distribution etc.

Comment: ok, sounds plausible. Thank you for your quick reply. :) I just thought about using spookyJS with node.js to simulate many users performing things on the site at the same time (login, etc). I know it's not the perfect approach but maybe it could work. Maybe someone can tell me if this approach could work?

Comment: If you have a dynamic app, something like phantom/casper could be the best way to get a realistic load profile across your cpu and database usage. So I don't think this really answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://loadbooster.com/

You can use CapserJS and phantomJS to distribute tests.